# Writing synchronous queries or async ones

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, multithreading

I am having an Asp.Net webforms page. I have 8 queries on the page on one of the complex page in the app. 2 queries can be cached and they are already cached but the other 6 requires hitting the DB. The page loads fine without any delay within 2 seconds. However, as a best practice along with performance I want to know if I should make them async. Problem is if I make them async, different connections have to be used for each query because currently I am storing the connection object in `HttpContext.Current.Items` and this won't be available if I am on different thread.

Should I be using `Task` api or should I leave them synchronous only? Please suggest best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best option is to combine that queries together. If this is completely not possible run them using at least on sql connection. Using async probably will not increase time until you use shared sql connection but I am think it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work on optimizing database access time then try to implement what Garath and mesterak suggested – that should give you additional performance improvements.

However, I must say that if my page was loading under 2s I wouldn’t really bother making any optimizations in this area.

Couple questions to ask yourself before you continue working on this:

- How do you know if its database calls that are making the biggest impact on page load?
- Have you seen the page trace or just assumed that it’s the database that’s making the biggest impact?
- What have you done to optimize other elements?

Here are couple other suggestions for you to try:

- Create page trace and examine the results. Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/82290/Step-by-Step-Guide-to-Trace-the-ASP-NET-Applicatio) on this.
- Examine your page using [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/) and see if there are any optimizations in other areas
- Check out these [tutorials](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/) on how to optimize other page elements

Answer (score 0):

I believe it depends on how you are making calls to your DB. It is possible to create a simple database handling class (static) that establishes one connection and then any queries performed can reuse the same connection object. Async calls just means you are performing them in parallel; this may improve user experience (faster performance), but the number of calls to the DB are the same. Perhaps we could better answer your question if you provide further details on how you are executing queries against your database in your code.

Comment: Faster performance is all what I require. Separate calls to DB isn't my issue and that won't hinder performance anyways because of connection pooling mechanism.